# Custom Object A 's field on Visual force page

Tags: visualforce

I have one vf page **ADetail** with standardcontroller **A** and extension **ADetailController** . I want to know which fields of A are used on vf page in controller. So I did `A.getRecords()` in controller but how can I filter field name from it .

thanks

Comment: Like I have to match it's field's from another object B so it want a list which contain all avilable fields on A . So by For loop I can match all fields avilable on A .

Answer (score 0):

You could a describe on A to get all of the fields that A has.  Then, iterate over that list, and see if any of those fields are populated on A, and compare them to B field values.  You'd probably want to use the SObject notation for accessing those fields.

Comment: Thnaks Kirill Yunussov . But it's a very lengthy process and like one field is on my page and it is null . So it will be not matched . Any Other approach .please share